# How do I make OpenSSL work with socat using Cygwin?

Tags: openssl, cygwin, socat

I'm trying to make sockat work with OpenSSL within Cygwin terminal:

`sockat - OPENSSL:192.168.7.128:443,verify=0`

error output:

`socat[1181] E unknown device/address "OPENSSL"`

despite the package being installed. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: have you tried replacing  `OPENSSL` with `ssl` ?

Comment: Check if OpenSSL feature is compiled:

socat -V | grep SSL

To my best knowledge, Cygwins Socat has it (#define vs. #undef).
In case you compile Socat yourself, you need the openssl-devel package.